# Add specific webpart to page via powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Delete please - not possible. Going to repost question in different section.

Comment: What's inside the webpart?

Comment: It is a handshake webpart, so it has all the settings I need. For some reason I cannot import it so I am trying to copy it from a site that I will use to house the web part.

Answer (score 0):

You're really close.

Get rid of the foreach loop but keep the bit about instantiating the web part instance, then call [AddWebPart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms416766.aspx) on your web part manager, passing in an instance of your new-object HSWebServiceRender.

Comment: I tried that but now I am getting the following error:
`New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At line:21 char:48
+                          $webPart2 = new-object <<<<  HandshakeWebParts.HSWebServiceRender
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand`
Even this does not work:

Comment: even if I try this it does not work and throws the same error:
even if I just try:
 `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("HandshakeWebParts")
                         $webPart2 = new-object HandshakeWebParts.HSWebServiceRender`

Comment: There's a problem with the constructor of the HSWebServiceRender class. It could be that it just won't run when not in a web site context (you can fake this, though). You might be able to get more info by running that script to throw that error again, then looking at `$error[0].Exception.StackTrace` in the powershell console. If that gets you the `MethodInvocationException` then do `$error[0].Exception.InnerException.StackTrace`

Comment: Here's an article on Faking an SPContext in PowerShell - https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2013/07/15/injecting-httpcontext-and-spcontext-into-your-powershell-scripts/